# How can a SearchView in the ActionBar be tested?

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, searchview

I can't find any examples or help in the JavaDocs on how to use an Android test to get at the SearchView in the Menu for testing. Is there a way to do it?

I would like to do do a `.setQuery("Foo", true)` or equivalent to test search in my app. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)

> Note: Although collapsing your action view is optional, we recommend
>   that you always collapse your action view if it includes SearchView.
>   Also be aware that some devices provide a dedicated SEARCH button and
>   you should expand your search action view if the user presses the
>   SEARCH button. Simply override your activity's onKeyUp() callback
>   method, listen for the KEYCODE_SEARCH event, then call
>   expandActionView().

If you have expanded the serach view for the KEYCODE_SEARCH event,then testing should be possible by using the instrumentation to inject events.

```
public void testSearch() { 
   Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation(); 
   instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH); 
   instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F); 
   instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O); 
   instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
   //Assert here for whatever you want. 
}
```

Make sure you have the inject permission in your manifest.

Comment: Whoa, that is ugly. However, if it works, you win. I will try it out tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Here it is in the wild: https://github.com/zostay/CPAN-Sidekick-Test/blob/master/src/com/qubling/sidekick/test/ui/module/ModuleSearchActivityTestHelperHoneycomb.java

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use monkeyrunner to do that : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

Comment: Can you be more specific? The documentation I see on the Android Developer's site seems kind of vague on the subject. I've seen a couple other sites mentioning some tools to use with it, but nothing definitive. I haven't seen anything clearly explaining how to use it and I don't know much Python. I can learn more if I need to, but I don't have enough information to even determine if that investment of time would be fruitful.

Comment: I never it, I think you can find some tutorials on Google